# Misunderstanding about flyback transformer and turn ratio

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

Here is the flyback that I m studying. It is a flyback transformer. 
[image]

I am confused about the different turns ratio. If I suppose the input voltage minimum and so the duty cycle maximum (i.e D = 0.5), according to the relation which gives the output voltage in function of the input voltage, we should have :

$$\frac{Vin_{minimum}}{Vout+V_{forward}}\ = N$$

Nevertheless according to this formula I do not get the different turn ratio of the transformer.

For example by using my formula, the turn ratio between the 24V output voltage and the input voltage should be :

$$\frac{290}{25}\ = 11.6$$

Nevertheless, the turn ratio of the transformer is :

$$\frac{52}{4+3+3+6}\ = 3.25$$

It seems to be very different from my formula ... I do not understand :( Besides the duty cycle is regulated from the 24V. Any turn ratio corresponds to what I find with the formula ... I obviously miss something ...

Here is what I think the bottom coil section should be superior or equal to the one which follow it. Look the figure at the top of the pictures
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: You do need to ask a question Jess and you do need to show the numbers you calculated. Your formula is correct but you can't have fractional turns, you must always round down N (increase secondary turns) and live with the consequences.

Comment: Thank you Andy for your comment. I edited the post for being more understable :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is in assuming the 24 volts is produced by all 16 secondary turns - look at the first tap point at the top of the 6 turn winding - this is the ground reference for those voltages. In other words the 24 volts is produced from 10 turns and not 16: -

[image]

I would say that the next error is in assuming that the minimum supply for the primary is 290 volts. This may not be your error but someone else's. Given the turns ratio of 52:10 to make the 24 volt output, I would say that the minimum DC supply on the primary is more likely to be 125 volts DC or around 87 V RMS after accounting for the bridge rectifier. It's likely that the minimum supply is 87 volts AC because that just about makes the transformer suitable for 85 to 264 volts AC i.e. the universal supply range of 85 - 264 V RMS.

Comment: You re right ! I don't know where was my mind ... I was so in despair.

For the next part, you may be right ! I ;) It clearly makes sense !!

Comment: Glad to help and lift the misery LOL.

Comment: "I m back ! " Question : Do you agree that the coil section at the bottom of the transformer shoud be higher or equal to the coil section which follow it, as the coil at the bottom provides the current of all the secondary supplies. (-15V; 7V5; 15V; 24V)

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by *the coil section which follow it*?

Comment: You re really fast ! The first/bottom coil is the one with 6 turns, the coil which follows it is the one with the 3 turns, then the 3 turns and finally the 4 turns. I'm sorry for my english. I try to do my best :D

Comment: The 6 turn coil provides -15 volts and the two 3 turn coils above it provide +15 volts with a centre-tap at +7.5 volts. I still don't understand your question though.

Comment: I might be wrong. I agree with your previous statement, nevertheless all the current/energy for the different supplies is coming from the bottom coil and it is then subdivided between the different coils according to their output power as it is a stacked transformer. It won't be the case if the transformer will not be stacked. I will edit the post in a few minutes

Comment: No, the return current for all the supplies is on the node marked in green \$\color{lightgreen}{\text{0 volts}}\$ on my modified picture above. The lowest 6 turns only supplies current to any load on the -15 volts.

Comment: The coils are acting as voltage source, as generator of energy.

Comment: *nevertheless all the current/energy for the different supplies is coming from the bottom coil* No it isn't.

Comment: Ok, Suppose we consider the same transformer without the -15 V, so just with the 3 turn, 3 turn and finally 4 turns. The current at the bottom in a stacked transformer is higher than the current at the top of the coil, whatever the different output power.  For having 24V, we need to use all the number of turn of the transformer, (ie 3+3+4). So it means some of the energy necessary to supply the 24V is containing in the bottom coil ? No ? in the first 3 turn ?

Comment: If I correctly understand you, you are saying that the current into each coil is the same whatever the transformer is stacked or not ?

Comment: Yes, some of the current in the lowest 3 turn coil is due to the load on the 24 volt output. And that load connects between to top coil (via a diode) and the 0 volts point. That will mean that the lowest 3 turn coil carries more current than the high winding (4 turn). I still don't understand your question though.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry to be not clear...  so in this case the coil section at the bottom (AWG) should be larger or equal (AWG lower) to the one which follows it ? In terms of power dissipation it seems to be logical that the coil which has the larger current has the larger section ? Did I miss something ? Does it apply to the transformer with the -15 V too ?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to have the lowest 3 turn coil have a larger copper wire (if needed). It doesn't apply to the -15 volt coil because any current circulates back to 0 volts and that coil doesn't contribute to any of the voltages on the positive side.

Comment: You re right ... You already told me ... Thank you again for your help !